# Is *musica* a *scientia* or an *ars*?

Tags: word-choice

If I understand correctly, *ars* would correspond to nowaday's "technical sciences" whereas *scientia* would correspond to "theoretical sciences".

Therefore, which word would best describe *musica*, as it was both a branch of [mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrivium) and a practice.

Comment: ars means everything, artistic and technical.

Comment: Your link doesn't say *musica* was a branch of mathematics, but it does say it's one of the liberal **arts**. It doesn't use the actual Latin term *artes liberales*, but the linked article for [liberal arts education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_arts_education) does. That said, your definition of *scientia* isn't Classical but Medieval; I actually don't know if your opposition between *ars* and *scientia* is even Medieval. Where did you get it?

Comment: @Cairnarvon I can't remember the first time I encountered it, but "artes et scientias" has about 10k hits in Latin on Google

Comment: One important point that Cairnarvon makes that renders this question impossible to answer is that you didn't narrow down your time: are you talking about Classical Latin or Medieval Latin? An answer one gives for one won't necessarily be the same for the other. If you thinking purely of "artes et scientiae", that could apply to people who don't know any Latin at all just using the terms because of the modern English "arts and sciences" in the US university system.